# write output to hbase table and a file using multipleoutputs

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is there any way to write map reduce output to an hbase table and a file using MultipleOutputs?

I am getting output in file but hbase table is empty. This is the code.

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(
            "/path/to/input.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/path/to/output"));
    job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "test");
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "file", FileOutputFormat.class,
            Text.class, Text.class);
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "table", TableOutputFormat.class,
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Put.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

I could write to hbase table and a file using MultipleOutputs. It is possible to write to additional outputs other than job default output using Multipleoutputs. Made the TableOutputFormat as the job default output and defined an additional output using MultipleOutputs which could write to a file. Please find the code snippet below. This is the driver code.

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setMapperClass(HBaseMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(HBaseReducer.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
    job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "table");
    job.setJarByClass(TableDriver.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(WritableComparable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Writable.class);

    //additional output using TextOutputFormat.
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
            WritableComparable.class, Writable.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

And in Reducer

```
private MultipleOutputs mos;
String path;

protected void setup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);

}

protected void reduce(WritableComparable key, Iterable<Writable> values,
        Context context) throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    for (Writable val : values) {

        sum += ((IntWritable) val).get();
    }
    result.set(sum);
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(key.toString().getBytes(), "C".getBytes(),
            "result".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(sum)));
    Put put = new Put(key.toString().getBytes());
    put.add(kv);

    mos.write("text", key, result, "text_file");

    context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(key.toString().getBytes()), put);
}

protected void cleanup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    mos.close();
}
```